# How do I backup/restore fzf history?

Tags: fzf

A very simple question, where is the data stored related to fzf?

I'd like to copy my "fzf history" from one machine to another... Can't seem to find this mentioned anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

History is stored in whatever file is specified with `fzf`’s `--history` option. Yours might be set in the `FZF_DEFAULT_OPTS` variable.

Answer (score 0):

`fzf` is using your shell history, so you need to copy your old file (`.bash_history` for example).